# How to get LSP like formatting in Emacs Elisp?

Tags: rust, emacs, language-server-protocol

Here is a scenario I use constantly in Rust development:

1. Rust LSP is always on.
2. I call the LSP feature "format current buffer" (or whatever it's called).
3. The LSP returns the buffer formatted (internally, the LSP uses `rustfmt`).

Since Emacs Elisp does not have an LSP implementation, how can I achieve something similar?
E.g., I wanna press some button and have the code in the buffer be formatted (not just indented, formatted).

P.S.
Emacs newbie here, transitioning from Neovim.

Comment: I believe that recent Emacs versions do have LSP support (but I'm no expert on this).

Comment: @Drew Yes, Emacs 29 that will be out soon, has a built-in LSP server based on the Eglot package, but that does not help since there is still no implementation of the LSP protocol for the Elisp language.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker, as you've already found, most (all?) of the available tools are listed at [this EmacsSE thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/283/28451). And I agree Elisp LSP might be not a bad idea. Now it looks like the common current solution is to customize formatting in own config and per project via [.dir-locals.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/.dir-locals.el), might be with a tendency to [this style guide suggestions](https://github.com/bbatsov/emacs-lisp-style-guide).

Comment: @Y. E. please make your comment an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De facto, *Elisp* formatting rules are defined in users config files, [.dir-locals.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/.dir-locals.el) per project, and often follow [this style guide suggestions](https://github.com/bbatsov/emacs-lisp-style-guide).

Since *Emacs 29*, for which [pretest is now available](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2023-05/msg00379.html), new function [`pp-emacs-lisp-code`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/156973639cc57dec47705f76f63c2ef3dc00a61d/etc/NEWS.29#L4557) can be used, which "applies formatting rules appropriate for Emacs Lisp code."

The docstring of the function currently states:

> Insert SEXP into the current buffer, formatted as Emacs Lisp code. Use
> the `pp-max-width` variable to control the desired line length. Note
> that this could be slow for large SEXPs.

A number of third-party packages for *Elisp* formatting are listed in [Command that formats (prettifies) Elisp code](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/283/28451) thread.